# Instantiating thread method from a different class in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

Can someone point me how to deal with the following issue? Basically, im trying to reuse code from the following example found at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SynchronizationContext.aspx
the only issue i dont understand is how i can instantiate the RUN method if it is found in a different class. Please see following code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void mToolStripButtonThreads_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // let's see the thread id
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Trace.WriteLine("mToolStripButtonThreads_Click thread: " + id);

    // grab the sync context associated to this
    // thread (the UI thread), and save it in uiContext
    // note that this context is set by the UI thread
    // during Form creation (outside of your control)
    // also note, that not every thread has a sync context attached to it.
    SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    // create a thread and associate it to the run method
    Thread thread = new Thread(Run);

    // start the thread, and pass it the UI context,
    // so this thread will be able to update the UI
    // from within the thread
    thread.Start(uiContext);
}


// THIS METHOD SHOULD GO IN A DIFFERENT CLASS (CLASS2) SO HOW TO CALL METHOD UpdateUI()
private void Run(object state)
{
    // lets see the thread id
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Trace.WriteLine("Run thread: " + id);

    // grab the context from the state
    SynchronizationContext uiContext = state as SynchronizationContext;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // normally you would do some code here
        // to grab items from the database. or some long
        // computation
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        // use the ui context to execute the UpdateUI method,
        // this insure that the UpdateUI method will run on the UI thread.

        uiContext.Post(UpdateUI, "line " + i.ToString());
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is executed on the main UI thread.
/// </summary>
private void UpdateUI(object state)
{
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Trace.WriteLine("UpdateUI thread:" + id);
    string text = state as string;
    mListBox.Items.Add(text);
}
}
```

### EDIT:

for instance, the run method is given me by someone else (another developer) and i need to run this method as a different thread in my UI thread (Main Thread or class Form1), however, whenever i run the thread (run method) i also need to update a ListBox `mListBox` using the UpdateUI method.

Comment: You can't, as it's private. Maybe you should tell us what you expect to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Run` should be static if you want to execute it without instantiating it's parent class.  Also, `Run` should be exposed as public, depending on the scope of how you plan on using it. e.g.

```
public static void Run(object state) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to do something like this?

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
var thread = new Thread(foo.Run);
```

(This is assuming you change Run to public)